# Beginner Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, groovy-console

I'm following the code examples in 'The Definitive Guide to Grails' by Graeme Keith Rocher, and have come across a rather unusual stumbling block.

Essentially, 2 domain classes exist - Bookmark & Tag.

**Bookmark:**

```
class Bookmark {
static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

URL url
String title
String notes
Date dateCreated = new Date()
```

}

**Tag:**

```
class Tag{
static belongsTo= Bookmark

Bookmark bookmark
String name
```

}

I'm instructed to launch the Grails Console (is this the same as the groovy console)and create a new object as follows.

```
def b = new Bookmark(url: new URL('http://grails.org/'), title:'Grails', notes:'Groovy')
```

This results in:

```
Result: Bookmark : null
```

According to the book, GORM automatically provides an implementation of an addTag method. So I code...

```
b.addTag( new Tag(name: 'grails'))
```

Only to get whammed with the error message:

```
Exception thrown: No such property: b for class: ConsoleScript1

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: b for class: ConsoleScript1 at ConsoleScript1.run(ConsoleScript1:2)
```

The author hasn't accounted for this in the book. I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: There is an error in the provided : you define twice the class Bookmark with the same code !!

Answer (score 3):

Are you reading the 1st edition of the book?  If so it's quite outdated.  The add* methods have been deprecated since 0.5. It was replaced by addTo* so do this instead:

```
b.addToTags( new Tag(name: 'grails'))
```

Assuming your code example shouldn't have Bookmarks defined twice (copy and paste error?) and Tag might look like this:

```
class Tag {
    String name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The groovy console is not the same as the grails console. To access the grails console, type `grails console` in your application directory - you should get a Java GUI app. It's possible that the example will work then because grails add some stuff to the standard Groovy.

Also, your problem isn't the addTag method, but the item `b` that you defined which cannot be found. Try entering the whole script into the console at once and executing it, instead of executing it line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however even when I enter in 'grails console' in CMD , the Java GUI app that launches is titled 'Groovy Console'.

Comment: Ah, you're right.. still, it does behave differently than the command line console, I recommend the GUI version as it is more consistent with how the appliaction itself works.

I was just thinking - I don't have the book and I don't know what version of Grails you are using - but shouldn't the syntax be `b.addToTags(..)`? That's what the auto method is called in Grails 1.1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.
With regards to the b.addtoTags(..) that is present in Grails, but in the book, it says addTag(..)

I decided to reduce everything to the bare minimum and its still failing.

Bookmark Class:
class Bookmark {
String title
String notes
}

...and in GroovyConsole, I type:
def b = new Bookmark(title:'Grails', notes:'Groovy')

which still results in:
Result: Bookmark : null

Would you know why it is null?

Comment: Don't know for sure, I turned off my work machine already so this is a bit of guesswork.. but maybe because the toString() method is not defined? Try defining it, e.g. something like `String toString() {return 'title}`

Comment: ..and that ' is of course too much - is there a way here to edit your own comments?